# Paypal Integration in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, paypal, paypal-sandbox

Dear Please tell me the Purpose of all fields here,

```
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" name="platnosci">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_cart">
<input type="hidden" name="upload" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="arest@arest.pl">
<input type="hidden" name="notify_url" value="http://www.google.pl/paypal.php">
<input type="hidden" name="item_name_1" value="Item description">
<input type="hidden" name="amount_1" value="34.00">
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="PLN">
<input type="hidden" name="shopping_url" value="http://www.arest.pl">
<input type="hidden" name="email" value="tester">
<input type="submit">
```

All these fields are necessary and what is the purpose of each field,
thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can refer this paypal developer page

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/Appx_websitestandard_htmlvariables/